# is there any way to politely ask HR for a second welcome packet?

Tags: human-resources, internship, onboarding

I recently started my second internship at a company after working there last summer. I enjoyed last summer's internship, and I received very positive feedback from my colleagues and manager about my performance.

Last year, I received a welcome packet from Human Resources with a company-branded frisbee, towel, and notebook (with a generic pen). This year, I was expecting the same, but did not get it. I know that they still gave them to interns so I was taken aback that I did not receive one.

I would really like the second towel and frisbee. Is there a way to politely ask HR for a second welcome packet or should I just deal with it?

Comment: What's impolite about just asking?

Comment: It might be better to ask for specific items and turn it into a compliment saying how much you like it and if you can get more, instead of the whole packet.

Asking for the whole packet really feels like being cheap and greedy, but that's just my opinion. I honestly don't think they care too much because they expect to have tons of these things, but I never worked in HR before.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to politely ask HR for a second welcome packet or should I just deal with it?

Of course there is a nice way to ask.

> Deal HR Person... I know I am a returning intern and already received a welcome packet last year but I was wondering if it is possible to get another frisbee and towel. I have really enjoyed those items and would really appreciate it. I completely understand if it isn't possible. Thank you!

However, an intern asking for a second round of free stuff could put a bad taste in peoples' mouths. So I would ask myself what is more important... being asked back for a second year to the internship where you are gaining valuable experience and presumably more pay than working at a grocery store or the $2 frisbee and $2 towel? I would focus on the benefits of the internship and purchase myself a new frisbee and towel if I had a need for them.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, internships are increasingly viewed as getting people to work for free or at salaries substantially less than they would if they employed a fully qualified individual.

Forgive me but the real question you should be asking is why you were offered a internship in the second year and not a proper paid job, albeit if the job is seasonal appointment? After all, they know who you are and should know and trust your skills and experience and ergo, they should be paying you appreciably more than an unknown first year intern (with or without a frisbee).

If you can only measure your worth by a frisbee, pen and towel, I rather think you need to be examining your self esteem and ask yourself and not HR why you are still even working for them.

Is this company so so bad that they are paying you the same rate as last year and the only thing you are fretting about is some low value giveaways? How many frisbees can any one person need after all ?

Comment: As a student I am only doing an internship. It is a software engineering position so it isn't exactly a seasonal job, but I was offered to work in between the two summers (which I declined), which still would have been as an intern